# Dynamically insert og:meta tags from backend

Tags: php, reactjs, single-page-application, meta-tags

I'd like to add social media sharing to my React SPA without SSR.

So when you share a link with specific parameters to Facebook / Twitter etc. you get a custom image/description/heading...

I've found this guide which is solving the problem, but in the NodeJS app.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-social-sharing-in-a-nodejs-single-page-application--cms-25530

Is it possible to do in backend which is using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Before reading the article, I came to the same conclusion as the author of the linked article. Social media sites gather og:meta tags by reading the HTML directly using simple HTTP GET requests. It is very, *very* unlikely that this og:meta parser is executing the JavaScript on your site (and waiting for it to finish rendering) so any client-side approach (e.g. using `react-helmet`) is bound to fail.

It simply isn't possible to generate og:meta tags without sever-side rendering. The article you link confirms this--they use Express, a server framework, to render og:meta tags.

However, what I interpret your post as asking is a way to insert og:meta tags via the backend while still serving up a React SPA to users. That's totally possible and the article lays out a great framework you can replicate in PHP.

I assume your PHP backend has some code that is serving up your React SPA. The most straightforward solution is to simply modify that code to also return og:meta tags in the `<head>` based on what route was requested. It's that simple. You can use simple string replacement to insert the tags, although a PHP HTML templating engine would be more professional and maintainable (the linked article uses a templating engine as well).

Based on the article, you can also clean this solution up by modifying the router to:

- Differentiate normal (human using a browser) requests vs. social media bot requests
- Return an HTML page with your normal React SPA code for browsers
- Return a barebones HTML page with og:meta tags for bots

This way your browser users don't get useless meta tags in their `<head>` and social media crawlers don't get useless `<script>` and `<style>` tags.

(Personally, since I'm lazy, I would serve up the same HTML to bots and users alike. I think the article's solution is clean but also a bit overkill.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `react-helmet` library to add elements into the head tag.

To install it:

```
npm i react-helmet // using NPM, or
yarn add react-helmet // using Yarn, or
pnpm i react-helmet // using PNpm
```

To use it, add this in the JSX of each page:

```
<Helmet>
  <meta property="og:title" content="..." />
  {/* more tags here */}
</Helmet>
```

Hope this solution is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unless using that library is the _only_ solution to solve the OP's problem, then please don't post answers only containing a link off-site to a third party library. Even if it is, just pointing to a library is not a good answer. Asking for libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic here for a good reason. And if that library gets deprecated/removed, the answer wouldn't be helpful for anyone anymore. An answer should be able to stand on it's own

Comment: It's not possible to use react-helmet for this without having server-sider rendering.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Roger that.

Comment: Considering that the OP already said that they can't even use this library, it doesn't really help them here. A good answer answers the question without needing to install something extra, if it's possible. Then you can always add a suggestion in the end for an alternative way by using a specific library.